# Can footer on Blog.Stackblah.com have links to other Stackblah Blogs?

Tags: feature-request, blog, footer

The title basically says it all! Just like the standard Stack sites, can the blogs also feature links to all other stack blogs? Makes it slightly easier to navigate to them when you are done reading the latest posts on one blog and give newer ones more exposure! For instance, until a while ago, I didn't realise there was a Blog.SF, as I was under the impression that Blog.SE covered all bases! :)

---

Or is there a common place where all StackExchange blogs are listed?

Comment: Can we have a site for blogs which is called StackBlah.org? Pretty please?! That name is awesome...